# Clear Redux Undo History

Tags: reactjs, redux

How can we clear the redux history?  I've gotten the undo and redo to work perfectly, but for some reason when I do clear history in the same format (and I've tried in the initTypes as well, it didn't work.

My Reducer with undoable:

```
    const allReducers = combineReducers({
    activeUser: activeUser,
    activeBrochure: undoable(activeBrochure, {
        limit: 20,
        undoType: "BROCHURE_UNDO", // define a custom action type for this undo action
        redoType: "BROCHURE_REDO", // define a custom action type for this redo action
        clearHistoryType: "CLEAR_BROCHURE_HISTORY"  // [beta only] define custom action type for this clearHistory action
    }),
});
```

My actions:

```
export const rerender = () => { return { type: "RERENDER_BROCHURE", payload: null } }
export const createNewBrochure = () => { return { type: "CREATE_NEW_BROCHURE", payload: null }; }
export const clearBrochureHistory = () => { 
    console.log("Action: Clear Brochure History!");
    return { type: "CLEAR_BROCHURE_HISTORY", payload: ActionCreators.clearHistory }; }
export const brochureUndo = () => { return { type: "BROCHURE_UNDO", payload: null } }
export const brochureRedo = () => { return { type: "BROCHURE_REDO", payload: null } }
```

Component wiring:

```
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        activeUser: state.activeUser,
        activeBrochure: state.activeBrochure.present,
        brochureHistory: state.activeBrochure.past
    }
}
        function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        selectUser: Action.selectUser,
        createNewBrochure: Action.createNewBrochure,
        clearBrochureHistory: Action.clearBrochureHistory,
        selectBrochure: Action.selectBrochure,
        deleteBodyPage: Action.deleteBodyPage,
        brochureUndo: Action.brochureUndo,
        brochureRedo: Action.brochureRedo
    },
        dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(NavigationBar)
```

My Component JSX:

{

```
        //CLICK YES FUNCTION
        this.setState(update(this.state, { askNewBrochure: { $set: false } }));
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("brochureBuilder") < 0) {
            hashHistory.push("/brochureBuilder");
        }


        this.props.clearBrochureHistory();
```

Comment: setting `clearHistoryType` should work fine - make sure you are using the latest *beta* version of redux-undo (`beta9-3` at the moment), as this feature is not implemented in the previous versions. Also make sure that the types are the same (which they seem to be, but you might want to use constants instead of plain strings). If it still doesn't work, it would be nice if you could put up a small github repo to reproduce the issue. BTW: What does `payload` do?

Comment: payload is the data passed to the reducer, whereas type is the string key should hook a reducer to create a new state based on said data input

I will try to make sure the types, as you say, are the same and see what happens